# Pull Conversion actions using Google Adwords API

Tags: google-ads-api

Can anyone please help me understand how to  pull conversion action performance through Google Adwords API using Python? I seem to not find anything related to pulling out conversion action data in Adwords library.

Answer (score 0):

you can use conversion action segmentation in most of the performance reports to get your data splitter across specific conversion actions. Just add `ConversionCategoryName` and `ConversionTypeName` to your report parameters.
Please note that if segment fields are used, you may get more than one row per reported item
[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing. It is available in Google Ads API or Google Adwords API? Currently, I am using Google Adwords API but do not see "ConversionCategoryName" and "ConversionTypeName" in any performance reports. Could you help me with any developer doc?

Comment: I've updated the post to reference the report config fields